# Clipping plane using scene kit?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, scenekit

Once the graphic designer provides the .dae file, I have a requirement to crop the certain portion of it using scene kit.

Like in http://www.osgart.org/index.php/Clipping_Planes , I want to achieve the same using scene kit. What are the different ways to achieve it?

Comment: Are you looking for to cut the model or only to render a portion in runtime?

Comment: Cut the model, so user can select the perticular portion of the model at runtime and can rotate/zoom/etc